# stack2py - A Python wrapper for API v2 [alpha]

Tags: library, python

### About

stack2py is a library which wraps the SE API (v2.1) for Python. It aims to provide a clean and complete interface to the user, giving them complete control and accessibility.
Although, currently it is by no means complete (and in alpha stages), it aims to:

- Be "Pythonic"
- Give the user control over the network connections
- Cover the entire API

### Code Snippet

Getting the latest question on stackoverflow

```
import stack2py
stack2py.make_auth_proxy({'http':'http://.....'}) # Has Proxy Support!!
so = stack2py.Site('stackoverflow')
so.get_questions()
print so.questions[0]
```

#### License

Licensed under [New BSD License](http://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause).

#### Download

The library is currently hosted at:
https://github.com/pradyun/stack2py/

There's not much to post about, but I can assure you that there will be lots in the next 4-6 weeks.

Before posting anything here, please consider the fact that this library is in alpha stages (and not really complete but still is useable)..